# Youtube / Chrome / Windows 10 sound issue

Tags: google-chrome, audio, windows-10, youtube

There is a strange issue with sound playback from Youtube videos in Chrome on Windows 10:

For some Youtube videos, it fails to play the sound, and the following oddities can be observed:

- Sound from other Youtube videos, and other websites, is played normally.
- Chrome has the little playback icon in the Youtube tab.
- In the Windows Sound Mixer, the "Chrome" and "System" bars show the current volume level, but nothing comes out of the speakers.
- Microsoft Edge plays the Youtube videos in question normally.

Two videos without audible sound in Chrome are [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KjiUUJdPGX0) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6rX4xv5-NvE). What I'm not sure about is whether the sound of these particular videos *always* fails on Chrome. I've just rebooted though, and the sound still fails.

Because the Windows Sound Mixer actually displays the volume level but nothing comes out, and because Edge plays the sound flawlessly, I suppose this is not purely a problem with the videos themselves, but that Chrome and/or Windows 10 are involved.

Does anyone have an idea how to address this issue?

Comment: What research have you done? Have you checked for a Chrome update?

Comment: Chrome is 47.0.2508.0 dev-m, the newest dev build. I realize dev builds might introduce bugs, but even if this is a new bug, how can it play so loud a silence that Windows shows a substantial volume bar?